# Executing a Query within another Query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, html

I am trying to execute an Sql query that relies on the output of another sql query for each loop.

I have 3 tables books, students and borrowed.

Books table has the full details of all books (b_id is primary key), student has full details of all students (s_id as primary key)  and borrowed is a table which has the s_id and b_id as foreign keys and each entry is created when a student borrows a book.

The relationship is one to many i.e Student can borrow one or many books or none but a book cannot be with more than one student. As such my b_id is unique in the table index.

My plan is to create a Html table that lists all students that have borrowed books and on clicking a student in this table a drop down table shows all the books borrowed by that student.

I  just can't seem to get the SQL query to run as I need the s_id from the first Sql query to get the next one to work. plus my drop down table isn’t functioning properly either.

Please help see code below

```
Click on a student to see books borrowed:
<table class="table2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Mat number/th>
        <th>Dept</th>
        <th>level</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $sql_query = "SELECT student.* FROM student, borrowed where student.s_id = borrowed.s_id Group by student.s_id;";

        $result =  $db->query($sql_query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $counter = 0;

            while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
            {
                $counter++;
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="btn"><?php echo $counter;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['matNo'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Dept'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['level'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="expand1"></th>
        <th class="expand1">Title</th>
        <th class="expand1">Author</th>
        <th class="expand1">Genre</th>
        <th class="expand1">ISBN</th>
    </tr>
   <tr><?php
               foreach($row as $studentid){

                   $sql = "SELECT books.* 
                           FROM books 
                             inner Join borrowed on books.b_id = borrowed.b_id  
                           WHERE borrowed.s_id = $studentid";

                   $result2= $dbs->query($sql);
                   while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <td class="expand1"><?php echo $row2['title'];?></td>
        <td class="expand1"><?php echo $row2['author'];?></td>
        <td class="expand1"><?php echo $row2['genre'];?></td>
        <td class="expand1"><?php echo $row2['isbn'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
                   }
               }
        }
    }
        $result->close();
        $dbs->close();
    ?>
</table>
```

This is my Script to create a toggle/collapsible table:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
            $(".expand1").toggle();
        });
        $(".btn2").click(function(){
            $(".expand2").toggle();
        });
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query does not need to be in a loop and you can use the first queries `s_id` in the where clause of the second query

```
           $sql = "SELECT books.* 
                   FROM books 
                      inner Join borrowed on books.b_id = borrowed.b_id  
                   WHERE borrowed.s_id = {$row['s_id']}";

               $result2= $dbs->query($sql);
               while( $row2 = $result2->fetch_array()){
    ?>
```

You will also have to remove one of the following closing `}`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. I can see the books each student borrowed.